# ADF: setCurrentRow in different views

Tags: oracle, jsf, oracle-adf

I'm using JDeveloper 11.1.1.7.0 and I have this problem.

I have two different views, which are opened in the same web browser, in different tabs (maybe this is an important issue):

- In *view1*, I have a *Search* button so, if data is found, show it, and if not, create it. Both ways, Search action ends accessing the related VO and making *setCurrentRow* programmatically
- In *view2* , I have another *Search* button, list data from the same VO in a table and, in the last column, there is a link with *setCurrentRowWithKey* operation with *{row.rowKeyStr}*. In view2, and next views in the related flow, there are only read operations.

So, my problem is this:

- Access view1 in tab1, make a search and view data (setCurrentRow is executed).
- Access view2 in tab2, make a search and view data in the table.
- Here, if I click on setCurrentRowWithKey link, it fails and gives me back this failure:

oracle.jbo.RowNotFoundException: JBO-25020: No se ha encontrado la fila de vista con la clave oracle.jbo.Key[1042 ] en ...

1042 is the key selected in view1.

Why has happened that exception? Is it possible to work in this scenario?

Any help would be very appreciated. Regards

EDIT: The .jspx code

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.1"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich">
  <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
  <f:view beforePhase="#{viewScope.myBean.pageAccess}">
    <af:document id="d1" binding="#{viewScope.myBean.d1}">
      <af:messages binding="#{viewScope.myBean.m1}" id="m1"/>
      <af:form id="f1" binding="#{viewScope.myBean.f1}">
        <af:pageTemplate viewId="/templates/templateReportes.jspx" id="pt1">
          <f:facet name="usuario"/>
          <f:facet name="contenido">
            <af:group binding="#{viewScope.myBean.g1}" id="g1">
              <af:panelGroupLayout id="contenidoCentral"  layout="vertical" halign="center">
...
```

Error is while loading page, not invoking any method:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, 'myBean' returned null
```

Comment: You said you are "making setCurrentRow programmatically" so i suppose you had implemented the code inside a managed bean. If so, what scope does it have? (have you tried the view scope?)

Comment: @endrik , thank you for your answer. I have readed about scopes, and your suggestion seems to be my solution. But I can't solve it. In adfc-config.xml, I change scope to 'view'; then, in my .jspx, I change all #{backingBeanScope.myBean} references to #{viewScope.myBean} and then, it raises this execution error:

javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, 'myBean' returned null.


I think view scope is right, but, how can I implement it? Thank you again

Comment: Well, this might tell that the reference is not correct or that the bean is not being initialized. Please, post the bean/jspx code and the complete stack trace to see what's going on

Comment: @endrik, thank you again. I'll put some code in the main message, but it's nothing special (or I think); so, no annotations or stuff like this. The bean code has component bindings with their related getter/setter. And adfc-config.xml has scope view.

Comment: Don't worry about the 'special' thing and about annotations :) (actually the adf configuration manages the beans so there is no need for them). But i want you to be clear about this statement: "Error is while loading page, not invoking any method"...it's not true, because you have this method call: f:view beforePhase="#{viewScope.myBean.pageAccess}" ...which means you are calling the pageAccess propoerty on page load (beforePhase). I'll return to the previous comment, asking you to post the code of your managed bean if it's not a problem

Comment: @Endrik, thank you again. Reviewing code to post here, I advertise a possible error, so the view is in a bounded flow. First, a simple view has some checks in the load method, and then, it's force to navigate to this view or not (returns an error). Maybe I should test with 'pageFlowScope' ? Excuse me and thank you.

Comment: Didn't know about this detail. In this case, yes, you should go with pageFlow if you haven't tried it yet.